# Lefschetz for topoi

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, topos-theory

The [Lefschetz fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem) is a nice theorem in topology which counts the number of fixed points (counted with multiplicities) of a continuous map $f\colon X\to X$ using the traces of the homomorphisms $$H^n(X,\mathbb Q)\to H^n(X, \mathbb Q)$$ induced by $f$.

Proving an analogue of that statement for schemes instead of topological spaces was a huge step towards a proof of the Weil conjectures.

The cohomology of schemes is a special case of the cohomology of topoi (consider the étale topos of a scheme), which makes me wonder:

**Question:** *Can one formulate and prove a Lefschetz fixed-point theorem for all Grothendieck topoi and geometric morphisms? If yes, does that theorem imply both the topological Lefschetz fixed-point theorem and its analogue for schemes?*

This question is motivated by Grothendieck's philosophy stating that topoi are the real objects of "topology". They are a very general type of "space" which "subsumes" (in a sense) all other spaces (topological spaces can be regarded as sheaf topoi, schemes can be regarded as étale topoi, ...). So conceptually it would be nice if one could generalize some of the theorems in topology and algebraic geometry to topoi.

Comment: First you need a definition of *fixed point* in the topos context.

Comment: Good point, @LeoAlonso! What about the naive definition? After all, there is a good notion of *point* of a Grothendieck topos, and any geometric morphism induces a map between the points.

Comment: The Lefschetz fixed point theorem, both in topology and in scheme theory, only applies to sufficiently nice spaces. It is difficult to imagine a generalisation to all toposes when we don't even have it for all topological spaces and all schemes.

Comment: Then it might be possible to prove it for sufficiently nice topoi. I'd call them *Lefschetz topoi*.